# animating a player bullet when hitting the space bar inside html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

what i am trying to do basically is drawing and animating a bullet when the player hit the space bar .my problem  the bullet is animating correctly but when you hold the space bar an infinite line of bullets is drawn  this is a jsfiddle that can explain what i mean : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/B2nUs/26/

the code :

```
   var Missiles = {
            collection: [],

            draw: function () {
                for (i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++) {
                    this.collection[i].draw();
                    // Missiles.collection.length = 0;
                }
            },
            update: function () {
                if (Missiles.collection.length > 0) {
                    for (i = 0; i < Missiles.collection.length; i++) {

                        Missiles.collection[i].update();
                        // Missiles.collection.length = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

        };
        var playerMissile = function (M) {
            Mx = this.x;
            My = this.y;
            MR = this.radius;
            Msp = 3;
            MDir = this.rot;
            M.draw = function () {
                ctx.fillStyle = "Green";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fill();
                //this.h*2 specify that the image is in the row 2 of the tiled image
            };
            M.update = function () {

                switch (this.rot) {
                    case 0: this.y -= 3; break;
                    case 90: this.x += 3; break;
                    case -90: this.x -= 3; break;
                    case 180: this.y += 3; break;
                }


            };
            return M;
        };
```

how can i make one bullet to be draw on each space bar hit even if the user hold down the space bar so i prevent this line of continuous bullets

Comment: The way you're implementing your key handling seems really roundabout and needlessly convoluted. Have a look at the mini jquery library called debounce, it should give you an idea how to get as many key events as you want. If you don't want to handle the events as-they-happen, you need to be placing them in a queue, or at a minimum, only reset the keydown variable *after you handle it*.

Comment: but as i can see it's not a keydown problem bcs all the keys works fine and even if you put a console.log to see if the space is working you will definitely see that is working fine . but i need a help in the code logic as i can't figure out why this messy bug is occurring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle an auto-fire by yourself.

Add two properties to your tank object

```
       lastShootTime : 0,  // time when we last shoot 
       shootRate : 300,    // time between two bullets. (in ms)
```

Then, shoot only if enough time elapsed since last shoot :

```
       shoot: function () {
           var now = Date.now() ;
           if (now - this.lastShootTime  < this.shootRate)  return;
           this.lastShootTime  = now ;
           Missiles.collection.push(playerMissile({
               x: this.x,
               y: this.y,
               radius: 2,
               rot: this.rotation
           }));
       }
```

Rq1 : handle a speed for each missile, and have tank speed added to the missile to avoid the tank marching on its own missile (or speed the missile quite a bit for a quick fix. )

Rq 2 : you do not destroy missile when they are too far : do it.

Just an idea : you might improve the shootRate if the player gets an upgrade or so. You might also handle the heat of the canon, and have the shoot rate drop / stops on overheat.

I updated your fiddle, see here :
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/B2nUs/27/

I also modified a few things, as you will see, so that the game is smooth and there's no blinking now.
( It works with requestAnimationFrame, i corrected a few var missing, update of tank is within the tank class, playerMissile is a proper class, and the update is time-based, so your game will behave the same on any device. )

Happy coding !!!

Comment: thank thank thank you so much for this wonderful answer i read the code and it's awesome .i just need to understand why did you use the dt variable and why are you multiplying the player and the missiles speed by this variable and second what is the different between `requestAnimationFrame` and `SetInterval` bcs i see much of tutorials that use `SetInterval`

Comment: You're welcome ! For both the requestAnimationFrame and the dt thing, maybe best is that i redirect you to a post a did some time ago : http://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/thoughts-on-the-javascript-game-loop/

Answer (score 0):

try using a keyup event instead, as the keydown fires constantly and keyup fires once...